# Как связать Domain Model с Data Access Layer (DAL) с использованием DataMapper

Tags: c#, база-данных, шаблоны-проектирования, data-mapper

Всем доброго дня)
В Интернете много статей про архитектуру ПО. Есть много описаний паттернов связи доменной модели с источником данных.

Я разработал доменную модель на C# и хочу связать ее с базой данных. Для связи с БД выбрал паттерн DataMapper (Репозиторий использовать не хочу - нет желания смешивать слой доступа к данным с доменной моделью). 
Однако я никак не могу понять, где непосредственно применяются классы DataMapper, если он определен в слое DAL? Ведь основная работа ведется с доменной моделью. Как осуществляется взаимодействие этих слоев? Пожалуйста, приведите простой пример кода (желательно на C#).

Comment: _Репозиторий использовать не хочу - нет желания смешивать слой доступа к данным с доменной моделью_ - так не смешивайте. Репозиторий относится к DAL

Comment: Задача DAL - предоставить интерфейсы для работы с базами

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ). Если я не ошибаюсь, репозиторий подразумевает включение методов работы с базой данных в сами классы доменной области. Меня такой подход не устраивает. Вопрос был про использование DataMapper)

Comment: Паттерн не допускает работу с базой непосредственно из domain layer. Он предоставляет **интерфейс** domain слою для работы с ней, но domain layer не знает о базе ни-че-го.

Comment: Был бы благодарен, если бы Вы привели пример кода) Я видел много листингов, но везде оба слоя были расписаны отдельно без взаимодействия.

Comment: К сожалению, у меня нет практического опыта использования паттерна `DataMapper` для того, чтобы поделится им с вами.

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Data-Mapper-Design-Pattern-50ad1c32 пример реализации DataMapper от MS

Comment: rdom, большое спасибо за пример. К сожалению, для меня остается открытым вопрос: на каком уровне архитектуры осуществляется взаимодействие DataMapper с доменной моделью.

Comment: Вообще-то репозиторий предполагает, что его методы будут использовать классы слоя бизнес-логики.

Comment: @Eladei реализация на уровне DAL, там и происходит